# Delete elements and rows from numpy arrays in a dict

Tags: python, numpy, dictionary

I have a dictionary with one- and two-dimensional numpy arrays. Based on the values of one array (here, class_ids), I want to delete corresponding elements in one-dimensional arrays and corresponding rows in two-dimensional arrays if their associated value in the reference array is different from a reference value (here, 3). My current dictionary looks like this

```
json = {'rois': array([[150, 340, 323, 437],
                       [230, 315, 361, 450],
                       [71, 136, 111, 152],
                       [68,  75, 101, 127],
                       [106, 264, 129, 273],
                       [70, 137, 109, 182]]),
        'class_ids': array([1,  2,  3,  3, 13,  3]),
        'scores': array([0.999424, 0.9991478, 0.98883635, 0.9819324,
                         0.85232574, 0.7136188], dtype=float32),
        'masks': array([[[False, False, False, False, False, False],
                         [False, False, False, False, False, False],
                         [False, False, False, False, False, False],
                         ...,
                         [False, False, False, False, False, False],
                         [False, False, False, False, False, False],
                         [False, False, False, False, False, False]],

                        [[False, False, False, False, False, False],
                         [
                            False, False, False, False, False, False],
                         [
                            False, False, False, False, False, False],
                         ...,
                         [
                            False, False, False, False, False, False],
                         [
                            False, False, False, False, False, False],
                         [False, False, False, False, False, False]],

                        [[False, False, False, False, False, False],
                         [
                            False, False, False, False, False, False],
                         [
                            False, False, False, False, False, False],
                         ...,
                         [
                            False, False, False, False, False, False],
                         [
                            False, False, False, False, False, False],
                         [False, False, False, False, False, False]],

                        ...,

                        [[False, False, False, False, False, False],
                         [
                            False, False, False, False, False, False],
                         [
                            False, False, False, False, False, False],
                         ...,
                         [
                            False, False, False, False, False, False],
                         [
                            False, False, False, False, False, False],
                         [False, False, False, False, False, False]],

                        [[False, False, False, False, False, False],
                         [
                            False, False, False, False, False, False],
                         [
                            False, False, False, False, False, False],
                         ...,
                         [
                            False, False, False, False, False, False],
                         [
                            False, False, False, False, False, False],
                         [False, False, False, False, False, False]],

                        [[False, False, False, False, False, False],
                         [
                            False, False, False, False, False, False],
                         [
                            False, False, False, False, False, False],
                         ...,
                         [
                            False, False, False, False, False, False],
                         [
                            False, False, False, False, False, False],
                         [False, False, False, False, False, False]]])}
```

Expected output

```
json = {'rois': array([[71, 136, 111, 152],
                       [68,  75, 101, 127],
                       [70, 137, 109, 182]]),
        'class_ids': array([3, 3, 3]),
        'scores': array([0.98883635, 0.9819324, 0.7136188], dtype=float32),
        'masks': array([[[False, False, False, False, False, False],
                         [False, False, False, False, False, False],
                         [False, False, False, False, False, False],
                         ...,
                         [False, False, False, False, False, False],
                         [False, False, False, False, False, False],
                         [False, False, False, False, False, False]],

                        [[False, False, False, False, False, False],
                         [False, False, False, False, False, False],
                         [False, False, False, False, False, False],
                         ...,
                         [False, False, False, False, False, False],
                         [False, False, False, False, False, False],
                         [False, False, False, False, False, False]],

                        [[False, False, False, False, False, False],
                         [False, False, False, False, False, False],
                         [False, False, False, False, False, False],
                         ...,
                         [False, False, False, False, False, False],
                         [False, False, False, False, False, False],
                         [False, False, False, False, False, False]]])}
```

I have tried with np.delete and del json[class_ids][item] but I get this error

```
ValueError: cannot delete array elements
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve what you want like this for example

```
import numpy as np

dictNumpy = {'rois': np.arange(10).reshape(5, 2),
             'id': np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 3]),
             'scores': np.arange(5),
             'mask': np.arange(30).reshape(2, 3, 5)}
refArr = dictNumpy['id']
refVal = 3
ind2rm = np.asarray(refArr != refVal).nonzero()[0]
for key, value in dictNumpy.items():
    axis2rm = np.asarray(np.array(dictNumpy[key].shape)
                         == refArr.size).nonzero()[0][0]
    dictNumpy[key] = np.delete(value, ind2rm, axis=axis2rm)
print(dictNumpy)
```

This prints

```
{'rois': array([[4, 5],
       [8, 9]]), 'id': array([3, 3]), 'scores': array([2, 4]), 'mask': array([[[ 2,  4],
        [ 7,  9],
        [12, 14]],

       [[17, 19],
        [22, 24],
        [27, 29]]])}
```

The only problem here is if any array contains at least twice `refArr.size` in its own shape. Then, only knowledge about the array can determine which is the correct axis to remove from in the call of `numpy.delete`.

Comment: Works for rois id and score but for mask dosnt work

Comment: Do you mind providing the result of `json['masks'].shape`?

Comment: result of json['masks'].shape (447, 450, 6) and my error is assert boxes.shape[0] == masks.shape[-1] == class_ids.shape[0]
AssertionError

Comment: Thanks, I have updated my answer so that things can be automated.